# If for an integer $n$, $\frac{f_1(n)}{f_2(n)}=\frac 47$, then $n$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Consider two functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ satisfying $$f_1(x)=
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> \sqrt{x} &; \sqrt{x}\in\mathbb{Z} \\ 
> 1+f_1(x+1) &; \text{otherwise} \\
> \end{array} 
> \right.
> $$
> and $$f_2(x)=
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> \sqrt{x} &; \sqrt{x}\in\mathbb{Z} \\ 
> 2+f_2(x+1) &; \text{otherwise} \\
> \end{array} 
> \right.
> $$
> If for an integer $n$, $\frac{f_1(n)}{f_2(n)}=\frac 47$, then $n$ is ?

A. $2$

B. $16$

C. $258$

D. $129$

**My attempt:**

Let $n=k^2-m$, where $m$ is the difference between $n$ and the next perfect square number.

So, $$f_1(n)=(1\times m)+k=m+k$$
and $$f_2(n)=(2\times m)+k=2m+k$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{f_1(n)}{f_2(n)}=\frac{m+k}{2m+k}=\frac 47$$
$$\Rightarrow m=3k$$

$\Rightarrow n=k^2-3k$

However, I am unable to obtain an integral solution for $k$ from either of the options.

The given answer is

> C. $258$

Can someone point out my mistake or suggest an alternate method?

Comment: I tried, 258 doesn't look like a valid answer.

Comment: Where is this question from?

Comment: @Filippo The question is from a mock test of an exam I'm preparing for.

Comment: @RiverX15 I'd say someone writing for the mock test messed up then.  (Either that or you have a copy error)

Comment: As a likely source of error, if $f_2$ is changed to $f_2(x) = 2 + f_2(x+2)$ in the case that $\sqrt{x} \not\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $258$ becomes a valid solution.  I'm guessing someone changed that $2$ to a $1$ by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was pretty stumped by this initially too, so I worked on it. Then I realised something:
$$(k-1)^2<k^2-m\leq k^2$$
and it is hence worth noting that
$$m<2k+1$$
For any $k \geq 1$,
$$3k \geq  2k+1$$
meaning that $3k$ is an impossible value for $m$ to take.

I wasn't initially convinced by this, so I went to Desmos to try it myself. This is what I got:
[image: Desmos Plot]

Surprisingly, the math DOES work out. So it seems that there is no solution.

Something I noticed in addition is that there seems to be the case that the minimum value for each "branch" seems to approach $\frac{3}{5}$, which I have not proved. But yeah, this was a pretty interesting exploration for me.

Edit: Brian Moehring in the comments explained why the $\frac{3}{5}$ arises. I'll put what they said here for easy reference and to explain the full story in one message:

> To show the lower limit of $\frac{3}{5}$, note instead that $m<2k−1$ and setting $m=2k$ gives a lower bound of exactly $\frac{3}{5}$ (with $m=2k−2$ approaching). There's also a value of $\frac{1}{2}$ when $n<0$.

Comment: To show the lower limit of $3/5$ note instead that $m < 2k-1$ and setting $m=2k$ gives a lower bound of exactly $3/5$ (with $m=2k-2$ approaching).  There's also a value of $1/2$ when $n < 0$ but otherwise this seems to be the full story.

Comment: Thank you for your insight!